# how to make an checkboxlist select only two item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have more than two checkboxlist. i want to limit users to select only 2 items for each checkboxlist.

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item 4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

using javascript/jquery. Please help

**SOLUTION:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table[id^=CheckBoxList]').each(function (index) {
                var id = '#' + this.id;
                $(id).click(function (e) {
                  if ($(id).children().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 2) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
                i++;
            });
        });

</script>
```

Thankz all :)

Comment: Couldn't you use a [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after this: **http://jsfiddle.net/KCr4d/10/**

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^make a reference to this file

$(function(){ // <-- doc ready starts (short handler for doc ready)

$('#CheckBoxList1 input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
   if ($('#CheckBoxList1').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});

$('#CheckBoxList2 input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
   if ($('#CheckBoxList2').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
}); // <---doc ready ends
```

You can check this out in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/KCr4d/10/**

Comment: you can put it in `doc ready` handler and make sure to load jquery above this script

Comment: just updated the answer. you can follow this way. **(1)** jquery api reference before any jquery script **(2)** put your script in the `doc ready` handler.

Comment: what kind of html is it generating `<asp:CheckBoxList`. pastebin is blocked here. we do not have access to this.

Comment: .aspx page => http://hastebin.com/mehinilovi.xml

view source of .aspx page => http://hastebin.com/falicokegu.xml

Comment: if i have more than 20+ checkboxlist how can i validate them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use count of `checked` checkboxes. You need to add the checked count of both checkboxes to ensure exactly two `selections` from both of them.

```
if($('[id*=CheckBoxList1]:checked').length + $('[id*=CheckBoxList2]:checked').length > 2)
{
  alert("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#CheckBoxList1 input[type=checkbox],#CheckBoxList2 input[type=checkbox]').bind('click',function(){
  if($(this).siblings(":checked").length > 2){
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate the number of checked items and cancel the events that would check additional items.

```
$("#CheckBoxList1, #CheckBoxList2").on("change click", function (e) {
  if ($("#CheckBoxList1:checked, #CheckBoxList2:checked").length > 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // add additional error code here;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function like this.

```
function CheckCheck()
{
    var chkBoxList=document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');    
    var chkBoxCount=chkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var i=0;
    var tot=0;
    for(i=0;i<chkBoxCount.length;i++)
     {
          if(chkBoxCount[i].checked)
          {
              tot=tot+1;
          }
     }

    if(tot>2)
     {
          alert('Cannot check more than 2 check boxes');              
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#CheckBoxList1, #CheckBoxList2").click(function (e) {
    if($('#'+this.id+' input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >2){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it aspx page I reckon:

```
$('#<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
   if ($('#<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2)
     e.preventDefault();
});
```